# How can I add library to Android-Emulator's lib folder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

I have **libTestLibrary.so** library and I want add it to Android-emulator's **lib** folder. How can I do this ?

I make following steps:

1. **Window** / **Open Perspective** / **Other...** / **DDMS**
2. Enter **File Explorer** tab.
3. Find **lib** folder and open it.
4. Press **Push a file onto device** and select library which I want to push to device, but then process starts and after some seconds it's terminated and error appears:

> ```
> [2011-05-19 12:26:34] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
> ```

---

#### Added. Dear Eric:

I see the post that you linked but I can't understand it, can you give example of following code for my problem or explain this  ?

```
adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
adb push su /system/xbin/su
adb shell chmod 06755 /system
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
adb install superuser.apk
```

#### Added.

I have write in command line:

```
C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb remount 
C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb push libDsmShared.so /system/lib/libDsmShared.so
```

and error appears:

> failed to copy 'libDsmShared.so' to
>   '/system/lib/libDsmShared.so': Out of
>   memory

#### Added

I have made the following steps:

1. **Launch Eclipse**
2. Go To: **Window -> Open Perspective -> Other ...**
3. Select **DDMS** from the opened dialog
4. Select "**File explorer**" tab.
5. Press "**Push a file onto the device**" and select library which I wish to push.

   > Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
6. Minimize all opened windows and **open Command Line**
7. Write: **cd C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools** enter
8. Write: **abd remount** enter

   > You will see remount successful
9. Maximize Eclipse and try step 5.

   > Failed to push selection: Out of memory

Error appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [How can I add library to Android-Emulator's lib folder](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/05/25/how-can-i-add-library-to-android-emulators-lib-folder-in-eclipse/)

#### Operation System: Windows 7, Eclipse

Here I present the steps how I add libraries to Android-Emulator's lib folder, it takes a week from me, but I have done all and want to share my results in order you can solve your problem very fast and effectively. So I will present steps how I done this:

1. Open Eclipse.
2. Open Command Line (cmd) and go to path there your android SDK located:

   > cd C:\android\android-sdk-windows\tools
3. Now we will run Emulator with given partition size, enter following command:

   > C:..\tools> emulator -avd EmulatorName -partition-size 512
   >
   > **NOTE:** EmulatorName - is the name of your emulator.
4. Wait until emulator starts and minimize Command Line ( don't close it ), open new Command Line (cmd) and go to path:

   > cd C:\android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
5. Run the command

   > C:..\platform-tools> adb remount
6. Go to Eclipse and open

   > Window -> Open Perspective -> Other ...
7. Select DDMS in the opened Dialog.
8. Select "File Explorer" tab.
9. Select directory \system\lib
10. Select "Push a file onto Device" and select library(s) witch you want.

### All Done !

### Useful links:

- [Run android emulator from command prompt](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/12/run-android-emulator-from-command-line.html)
- [Stackoverflow Android Questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9519/how-to-solve-failed-to-push-selection-out-of-memory/9531#9531)

Answer (score 0):

In case of linux, I tried the following steps and it worked:

i) Use command 'adb shell'

ii) traverse to '/system/xbin'

iii) use 'ls' command to locate 'su'

iV) use 'su' command

V) Change permissions using 'chmod 777 /system/lib'

Comment: do this step before step I) adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system

Comment: Before the above step do this step - 'emulator -avd EmulatorName -partition-size 512'